# EPERM: operation not permitted error in React Native Project

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

React native is not build my project on cmd. Here is an error when I try to react-native run-android command

When I try it on Android Studio, it show second error. How can I fix it ? [image]

[image]

Comment: Hello,
Which RN version and Android Studio version are you using?

Comment: Hey. Android Studio 3.6.1 and RN version is 0.62

Comment: `watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean -f && npm install && react-native run-ios `

can you try with this command? If it is still not working, I need to see the example code or even need to learn what did you add before this error appears.

Comment: i'm using windows and i'm not using watchman .

Comment: You need to use watchman to React Native. You can simply install watchman for Windows.